# Where does $b(10)$ goes under this automaton

Tags: group-theory, automata

[image]

This is finite state automaton for Grigorchuk group. I have never studied automaton formally, so I wanna check is it fine the way I am doing it. 
Here $\epsilon$ change the first entry on string from 0 to 1 and vica versa.

If I calculate $d(10011)$ that means I put $10011$ in d circle, $1$ inside circle means identity automorphism i.e. $1_e$ , so it remains $10011$ then as first digit is $1$ so it goes to b, so now will b act $1_e$ on $0011$ i.e. it goes to $(1, b(0011))$  and then under $1_e$ 0011 remains 0011 and then detecting 0 it goes to $\epsilon$ which acts on 011 and it becomes 10111 and then goes to final state. I think I am correct with this understanding of automaton working,

but now the **problem** is if I calculate $b(10)$ it goes to $(1,c(0))$, now reading $0$ c sends it to a, which has to apply $\epsilon$ to $\phi$ (empty string), what does this mean. What is then $b(0,1)$, it didn't reach final state.

Comment: It seems that $d(10011)\to b(0011) \to a(011) \to final$.  You weren't deleting the $0$ on leaving $b$. Wouldn't the same issue arise if you try to compute $b(111)?$ or any string of all $1$'s?  You go around the $b,c,d$ loop cutting off the leading bit each time.  Eventually you run out and need to apply $1$ to $\phi$

Comment: can you explain $b(111)$, I am confused now. $d(10011)=(10111)$, I know this. I cannot delete 0, as far as I know

Comment: $b(111)$ was a new stating case.  My read of what you did in each block was to process the leading bit according to the $1$ or $\epsilon$, use the resulting leading bit to determine which path to take, and enter the next state with the first bit deleted.  I may be misunderstanding the process.  My point was that if you are in any of states $b,c,d$ with the bit string all $1$'s you will never leave the loop until the string is exhausted.

Comment: Yeah Ii see that now, but then how can we calculate $b(111)$ by automaton, so this automaton is useless, then why we use it as grigorchuk group automaton

Comment: Maybe inputs that do not get to the final state are not allowed?  The only failures come from all $1$'s or all $1$'s with a trailing zero when you get to the zero in state $b$ or $c$.  Any time you have a zero before the last bit you will get to final.  I'm just guessing.